# Differentiation under the Integration Sign

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have difficulty with the following question:

[image]

My understanding is that I can partially differentiate the integral with respect to any parameter (in this case, a or b) to obtain a derivate of the initial function.

My problem is that when I partially differentiate the integral with respect to a or b, I obtain the following:

[image]

I am unsure how I could obtain anything useful by evaluating either integrals (and then integrating that result to obtain $g(x)$). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The expression on the right is not a function of $x$; the $x$ is integrated out. It's a function of $a$ and $b$. That makes your computations on the paper all incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t quite understand. I can see that the expression on the right no longer contains x, but how can you integrate out x?

Comment: Integrating $x$ out means exactly this. After integrating over $x$ the expressions on the right don't depend on $x$ anymore. Thus it is bad/wrong notation to write $g(x)$. It should be $g(a,b)$. In particular the notation $g'(x)$ doesn't make any sense as in the your first case it denotes a derivative with respect to $a$ and in the second one wrt $b$.

Comment: @ShomariMills-Legerton: Using my answer, have you been able to figure out the Integrals?

Answer (score 2):

I only show you how to calculate the integral $I_1$. The second one is quite similar.

Start with $$\frac\pi {\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}=\int_0^\pi \frac {dx}{a+b \cos x}.$$

Differentiating twice with respect to $a$ you get 
$$\frac {2a^2+b^2}{(a^2-b^2)^{5/2}} \pi = \frac {\partial^2}{\partial a^2} \frac\pi {\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} =\frac {\partial^2}{\partial a^2} \int_0^\pi \frac {dx}{a+b \cos x}\\
= \int_0^\pi \frac {\partial^2}{\partial a^2}\frac {dx}{a+b \cos x} =2 \int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{(a+b \cos x)^3}.$$

Evaluating at $a=5, b=3$ and dividing by $2$ should give the desired result.

Comment: I apologise greatly for the delay in responding. Your answer helped me greatly and I understood what to do using it. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: @ShomariMills-Legerton Glad I could help. I would appreciate it if you accept my answer.